# Using FFmpeg with Nvidia GPU acceleration

Tags: ffmpeg, gpu, hardware-acceleration

I’m using Using FFmpeg with NVIDIA GPU Hardware Acceleration :: NVIDIA Video Codec SDK Documentation for Windows 10

All goes well until I hit the last three commands:

•   Goto nv-codec-headers directory and install ffnvcodec

make install PREFIX=/usr

•   Go to the FFmpeg installation folder and run the following command.

./configure --enable-nonfree –disable-shared --enable-cuda-sdk --enable-libnpp –-toolchain=msvc --extra-cflags=-I../nv_sdk --extra-ldflags=-libpath:../nv_sdk

•   Compile the code by executing the following command.

make -j 8

I cannot get the ‘make’ command to work – I get  'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
I did try the next command, the ./configure one, this was also rejected.

The documentation is : https://docs.nvidia.com/video-technologies/video-codec-sdk/ffmpeg-with-nvidia-gpu/

Can anyone please help with this?

Comment: You do not have make installed, it seems. The documentation that you are following should indicate the prerequisites to build ffmpeg, but you have not fulfilled them.

Answer (score 0):

Generally if you are compiling software from source on linux you need to have many different build tools installed. Most distributions bundle all the basic software compiling tools into a single virtual package.

On debian and ubuntu you need to

apt install build-essential